# AWS ALB ingress horrible performance on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have simple web application deployed to Kubernetes cluster (EKS) with [aws load balancer controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller) ingress

[image: schema]

When accessing app in the intended way on ALB endpoint the performance is very poor (2-3x worse than regular deployment on bare metal instance). Benchmark was done with [Hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey)

```
$ hey -t 30 -z 1m https://k8s-default-ingre-fdeb4c8b98-1975505070.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
# 5-10 reqs/s
$ hey -t 30 -z 1m http://172.16.3.37/  # from another pod accessing directly by its IP
# 20-30 reqs/s
```

If accessed from same/another pod or from different instance(node) when exposed as a `NodePort` performance stays the same, so I'm assuming something wrong with ingress/ALB.

How to identify bottleneck and debug such kind of an issue?

Here's my config

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/healthz/"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn:  "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1::certificate/cert"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ssl-redirect
            port:
              name: use-annotation
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Is there an overhead for ssl termination?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try and run kubernetes networking benchmark on both the clusters (bare-metal and EKS) -
   https://github.com/InfraBuilder/k8s-bench-suite

This shows how pod2pod and pod2svc latencies are on both clusters. If drastically different, it must probably be the underlying network -

2. Run iperf3 benchmark between nodes -
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/

This would probably give you an idea of how nodes separated far apart on EKS cluster impact latencies, uneven networking bandwidth, etc.

If the latencies are somewhat similar, you might want to dig into your application code using something like jaeger or application profiler to get breakdown of latencies.